# How to get a complete crash log from PLCrashReporter

Tags: ios, crash, plcrashreporter

I decode the plcrash log from PLCrashReporter, but some information not complete:

```
Incident Identifier: TODO
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
...
Exception Type:  SIGBUS
Exception Codes: BUS_ADRERR at 0x1
```

But the crash log I get from Organizer is:

```
Incident Identifier: 79A8A9E4-9FD2-4A53-B43F-DC32C47AA073
CrashReporter Key:   a767dd53c828e7977d7770d6d5c3c4238a2b525e
...
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
```

How can I get the correct Incident ID and CrashReporter Key(I do need this)? Thanks.

BTW, The PLCrashReporter's log does not show the thread name of the crash stack.

Comment: You should post this on the PLCrashReporter website (or look through the existing issues first). You don't need the Incident Id or the CrashReport Key. I have no trouble symbolicating crash logs from PLCrashReporter as-is.

Comment: Does anyone have answer for this question,

Problem I have observed is this, Xcode seems to use these fields to unique the reports. so, if you try to symbolicate two reports, both with TODO, it won't recognize them as being different, and it seems to just ignore the second one

Comment: I modify the source code to solve the problem, but i'm not sure if I did bad work or not, some crash stack seems not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Swift code:

```
let crash = PLCrashReportTextFormatter.stringValueForCrashReport(report, withTextFormat: PLCrashReportTextFormatiOS)
print("Report: \(crash)")
```

Objective C code:

```
NSString *crash = [PLCrashReportTextFormatter stringValueForCrashReport:report withTextFormat:PLCrashReportTextFormatiOS];
NSLog(@"Report: %@", crash);
```